# How to align text in a table using markup

Tags: confluence

I have a table described using Confluence markup.

```
||heading 1||heading 2||
|cell A1|cell A2|
|cell B1|cell B2|
```

I need to align the text in some cells to the right, in some to the center. Can this be done using markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to apply table alignment for Confluence using a markup. This can be achieved by HTML storage format.